# i need to obtain this mysql output after join

Tags: mysql, sql

i have these tables

```
1.table class(classname)
2.table flight_class(flightno,classname,fare)
```

class have rows(`economy,first,buissness`)
flight_class have rows(
    `AI77,economy,5000
    A177,buissness,6000`
    )

I need to obtain following output for a particular flightno

```
Classname fare
economy   5000
first     null
buissness 6000
```

i tried `select classname,fare from class left join flight_class using(classname) where flightno='AI77';`

but it is not working as it returns only rows and not giving all rows in table class(left join)

`economy   5000
 buissness 6000`

Comment: Try `select class.classname,fare from class left join flight_class on flight_class.classname=class.classname where flightno='A177'`

Comment: And try to include any error messages you get, next time when you ask a question.

Comment: `'Buissness'` does not equal `'buissness'` and `'A177'` does not equal `'AI77'` so your join returns no rows as there are no matches between these values. 'Business' is the correct spelling of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you where condition to on clause

```
select class.classname,fare 
from class
 left join flight_class
 on (class.classname=flight_class.classname AND flight_class.flightno='A177') ;
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64e0a/2)

Comment: Worked like a charm.thnx dude!